# On label click return its radio group name

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/Yuxfv/2/

I want to be able to click on a label, and see which radio button group it belongs to. I tried this, but it always finds the first input after li (name=left), not the one closest to the label. How do I fix that?

```
$('input[type=radio]:enabled + label').click(function () {
    var thisGroupName = $(this).closest('ul').find('input[type=radio]:enabled').attr('name');
    alert("group name: " + thisGroupName);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" class="radio-red" name="left" id="a1">
        <label for="a1">a1</label>
        <input type="radio" class="radio-blue" name="right" id="a2">
        <label for="a2">a2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" class="radio-red" name="left" id="b1">
        <label for="b1">b1</label>
        <input type="radio" class="radio-blue" name="right" id="b2">
        <label for="b2">b2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" class="radio-red" name="left" id="b3">
        <label for="b3">b3</label>
        <input type="radio" class="radio-blue" name="right" id="b4">
        <label for="b4">b4</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: are you trying to get the name of the radio button which the label was made for?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Yuxfv/3/

Comment: @Ahmad, yes.prev() below solved it.

Comment: @user2011960 okay, Thought you had something else in mind :)

Comment: @user2011960 You should accept an answer so this question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont go to `ul` and come back into `li`. Try using `prev()` if you need to get the `input`'s group :

```
$('input[type=radio]:enabled + label').click(function () {
   var thisGroupName = $(this).prev('input[type=radio]:checked').attr('name');
   alert("group name: " + thisGroupName);
});
```

To get more specific, you've got `for` attribute with you. why not use that?

```
$('input[type=radio]:enabled + label').click(function () {
       var thisGroupName = $("#" + $(this).attr("for")).attr('name');
       alert("group name: " + thisGroupName);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need  this:

```
$('label').click(function(){
 var forRadio = $(this).attr('for');
 var groupName = $('#'+forRadio).attr('name');
alert(groupName);
```

});

I have made a  jsfiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/psmkw/

Answer (score 0):

In the code example you provided you could also look up the radio button explicitly by using the 'for' attribute of the clicked label.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=radio]:enabled + label').click(function () {
        var forName = $(this).attr('for');
        var thisGroupName = $('#' + forName).attr('name');
            alert("group name: " + thisGroupName);
    });
});
```

It is working in this jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Yuxfv/4/

Answer (score 0):

there is no point in traversing the DOM in that way, the label has a reference to the element. which it use to click it when you click the label.

```
 $('input[type=radio]:enabled + label').click(function () {
    var input_id = '#'+$(this).attr('for');
    var group_name = $(input_id).attr('name');
    alert("group name: " + group_name );
 });
```